# how can i use two mysql query with user defined variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, variables

```
select @min_price:=min(prd_sale_price),@max_price:=max(prd_sale_price) from ct_product;
select * from ct_product where prd_sale_price=@min_price or prd_sale_price=@max_price;
```

This query works in mysql console

but

```
$query = "
select @min_price:=min(prd_sale_price),@max_price:=max(prd_sale_price) from ct_product;
select * from ct_product where prd_sale_price=@min_price or prd_sale_price=@max_price;
";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

this code raise error in php

so, I tried this

```
$query="
select * from ct_product, (select @min_price:=min(prd_sale_price),@max_price:=max   (prd_sale_price) from ct_product) as b 
where prd_sale_price=@min_price or prd_sale_price=@max_price
";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

that works

...

```
$query = "
select @min_price:=min(prd_sale_price),@max_price:=max(prd_sale_price) from ct_product;
select * from ct_product where prd_sale_price=@min_price or prd_sale_price=@max_price;
";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

What's the way that this code would work well without modification as my second way?

Comment: mysql_query, accepts ONE querry only, not 2

Comment: Any reason you can't use some flavor of join in your query? As Dagon says, mysql_query will only take one query for one result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two calls to `mysql_query`:

```
$query1 = "select @min_price:=min(prd_sale_price),@max_price:=max(prd_sale_price) from ct_product";
$query2 = "select * from ct_product where prd_sale_price=@min_price or prd_sale_price=@max_price";

mysql_query($query1);
mysql_query($query2);
```

Variables are associated with a database connection, so they'll persist between the calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. i try and your code work very well

Answer (score 0):

in PHP  `mysql_query()` can handle only one query at a time

You can't make this method handle 2 query at the same time

what I can suggest is using mysql_query() for every query